# Open in a New tab feature on Internet Explorer 8 on "windows 7" 64 bit

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I just built a new machine and installed the windows 7 ultimate 64 bit on it. Internet explorer 8 is giving me major pains. whenever I try to open a link in a new tab, it hangs. Although the new tab works fine if I just click on the new tab. It is just the "Ctrl+Click" or "Right Click" and "Open with new tab" that hangs the IE for around 30 seconds or so and then opens the link in a new window.

I have already tried out the solutions given here: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/e312e580-1cbc-496b-8c6b-b69b8535a7bb?prof=required

Nothing works. The long batch file solution got pretty close, but it is giving an access denied on the "fixing registry bugs" part.

This is my first question at stackoverflow. Help me out guys...

Comment: You got it wrong with stackoverflow -- this is a programmer's den, try superuser.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ran the batch file as administrator and still got an access denied error, then I'd say you've got some more problems than just IE being messed up and not opening tabs. If everything else is working fine and just IE is giving you fits, then I might just suggest moving to a different browser, such as:

[Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)

[Opera](http://www.google.com/chrome)

[Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/)

[Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html)

*Not in any specific order.